# Getting elements (tuples) by group of 2 from a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list containing some coordinates ordered as tuples:

```py
list =    [(316852,4.99246e+06), (316858,4.99244e+06), (316880,4.99246e+06), (316863,4.99248e+06), (316852,4.99246e+06)]
```

and I would like to get its elements by group of 2. The result expected is something like this:

```py
(316852,4.99246e+06), (316858,4.99244e+06)
(316858,4.99244e+06), (316880,4.99246e+06)
(316880,4.99246e+06), (316863,4.99248e+06)
(316863,4.99248e+06), (316852,4.99246e+06)
```

Any idea on how to obtaining this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
list = [(316852,4.99246e+06), (316858,4.99244e+06), (316880,4.99246e+06), (316863,4.99248e+06), (316852,4.99246e+06)]

for x in range(0, len(list)-1):
    print(list[x], list[x+1])
```

Comment: Thanks dude, I didn't think about decreasing the counter by 1! In this way, the task has become easier =)

Answer (score -1):

you can try this :

```
print([list[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(list),2)])
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers.